# Why is my node.js function not returning SQL Server data

Tags: node.js, sql-server

I have the following node.js code that is supposed to pull data from a SQL Server database. Any idea why my function is returning "Nothing to send" even though there is data to be returned from the database. What am I missing?

Your assistance will be much appreciated!

```
function findCasesAndSendMessage(blnExitProcess) {

    var http = require('http');
    
    
    options = {
        host: HOST,
        port: PORT,
        path: '/DailySummary',
        method: 'GET'
    };
    
    var req = http.request(options, function (res) {

        var msg = '';
    
        res.setEncoding('utf8');
    
        res.on('data', function (chunk) {
            msg += chunk;
        });

        res.on('end', async function () {

            var strMessage = '';

            arrRows = JSON.parse(msg);

            for (var i = 0; i < arrRows.length; i++) {

                objRow = arrRows[i];

                strMessage += objRow.strText + "\n";
            }
        console.log(strMessage);
            if (strMessage.length > 0) {
                console.log("Message sent!");
                await sendMessage(strMessage);
            }
            else
            {
                console.log("Nothing to send!");
            }

            if (blnExitProcess == true)
            {
                setTimeout(exitProcess, 10000);
            }
        });
    });

    req.end();
};
```

Comment: where is the database connection and database accessing part

Comment: Do you not know how to debug your code? It looks like your GET request is not returning anything. Is there some way you can verify that?

Comment: Try entering the http request directly into a browser and confirm that some data is actually being returned.

Comment: Print data to the log in the on:data handler and to report the content of the json msg before it is parsed. Are you sure the json structure is an array and that the array contains objects with the property `strText`?